# How can I define the spacing following a paragraph in prawn pdf?

Tags: prawn

I'm rendering texts in a prawn pdf report and would like to define the exact spacing after a paragraph.
I found :leading, which helps to define the line height, but nothing to define the spacing after a new paragraph (within the same cell or bounding box).

Answer (score 0):

So far I have not found out how to define the spacing as such, but I still think I found the problem why the space was too large.

I add the statement

```
puts content.dump
```

to my class to print the content on the console.

In the cases where I had a paragraph in the content, the paragraph was replaced by \n\n.
Example:

```
<p>Text</p><p>Text</p>
```

is changed to

```
"Text\n\nText\n\n"
```

As I anyway use an html sanitizer method to remove undesired html tags, I could extend the method with the following:

```
res = content.gsub(/\n{2,2}/, "\n")
res = res.gsub(/\n{3,}/, "\n\n")
```

This solved the problem for me.